# React-Slick wraps content in div when shouldn't

Tags: reactjs, slider, slick.js, react-slick

React-Slick worked as should some days ago, now I updated the version and it wraps all slides in a div that breaks the old structure and behaves weird.

I've tried to downgrade and remove all settings but it didn't help.
I know it's weird that after the downgrade to the previous version I have the same problem, but I am completely sure that 2 days ago it worked correctly.

Here is how I use react-slick:

```
<Slider {...sliderSettings}>
  <div><h1>test</h1></div>
  <div><h1>test 1</h1></div>
  <div><h1>test 2</h1></div>
</Slider>
```

And here are the settings:

```
const sliderSettings = {
  dots: true,
  lazyLoad: true,
  className: 'slider',
  dotsClass: 'dots',
  arrows: false,
  autoplay: true,
}
```

Here is the markup in the browser:

```
<div data-index="0" class="slick-slide" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" style="outline: none; width: 1275px;">
  <div> <<-- This div shouldn't be here
    <div tabindex="-1" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
      <h1>test</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with the new version, `0.23.1`. For some reason it wrapped all slides in a `div`, that would break the structure and the props would arrive on an unexpected element.

Fixed it by downgrading to `0.16.0`.